# How to post test data with different users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am running the following test

```
test "create if user1 or user2" do
    [@user1.id, @user2.id, @user3.id].each do |user_id|
      assert_difference('Message.count') do
        post :create, {:message => 'blah blah'}, {:user_id => user_id}
      end
    end
  end
```

this code does 3 loops as expected, but it post only with the first user(in this case user1).
therefore I don't get failure when user3 try to post (because it's actually still post with user1)

when I change in my application controller

```
def current_user
  @user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

to

```
 @user = User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
```

My test Works fine, but I don't understand why.

I thought that every post should run the whole app from scratch as happens in web-browser

Comment: gilsilas I deleted my post, since I doubt it's a mistake. Something else is going on I guess. Disregard my post..sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to think of this is that each test is equivalent to a single request. If you make a single request, you only want to look up the user once, so caching it with the `||=` in the `current_user` method makes sense. After the request, the cached value is discarded.

A single test doesn't discard the cached value, so the `current_user` always returns `@user1`. You need to either run multiple tests, or explicitly logout the user after the test.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code works without the ||= is because that effectively caches the value of the result of "User.find..."  See the following:

```
# Behavior of 'or equals' operator, ||=
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > a = 1
=> 1 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > a = 2
=> 2 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > a ||= 3
=> 2 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > a
=> 2
```

"Or equals" says "assign the value to the variable unless the variable already has a value."

Comment: but this is exactly what they did in this railcast http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch

Comment: Sure, but with your test, you need to log out every user after they log in.  I usually do something like this:

Answer (score 0):

It might help to understand that even though you have user1, user2, and user3 all connecting to your web app at the same time, there is a session for each user but only one 'current_user' per session.

With this in mind, it looks like your test is not correctly changing the user **session** that's being used. Instead, it's just looking for a `current_user` which again, is not actually changing the user session.

You need to figure out a way to correctly change the user sessions that you're using to do the post. For example, logout and log the next user in at the beginning of your loop.